# pax-provision without gogo shell

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, pax, gogo-shell

I recently started with osgi. I'm using pax tools to generate and deploy my bundles. I'm trying to create a console application, but everytime I launch pax-provision command gogo shell is fired. I also want to know what is the difference between pax-provision and pax-run ( I don't use pax-run ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned off the gogo shell by editing the pom.xml in the base directory of the projec, by adding --noConsole to configuration :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.ops4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-pax-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <configuration>

      <provision>
        <param>--platform=felix</param>
         <param>--noConsole</param> 
      </provision>
    </configuration>
    <executions>

      <execution>
        <id>ide-support</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>eclipse</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>

    </executions>
  </plugin>
```